# Is it possible to add formatting to html using JS regexes

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Is it possible to add formatting to html using JS (what can easily be done in Office editors)?

This is what I want to do:

```
let htmString = "<p>baz foobar</p><p>foo<i>bar</i></p>";
let reg = RegExp( "^fooba", "g" );
let htmModified = myFunction( htmString, reg, ["<u>", "<\/u>"] );
console.log( htmModified );
```

**Output:**

```
<p>baz foobar</p><p><u>foo</u><i><u>ba</u>r<i/></p>
```

(being after `<p>` is interpreted as the beginning of a line, thus only the 2nd `foobar` matches /^/)
[image: transformation]

Comment: Possible? Sometimes. A good idea? Almost never, use a proper HTML parser instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks! Could you give an advice to a newbie, which parser to use?

Comment: `DOMParser`, for example

Comment: Concept sounds simple if all you have is raw text. But in your case you also need to find the `<i>` and wrap it inside the `<u>` or will break the html if you remove the star of `<i>`

Comment: @charlietfl I need to find text outside the tags (which is actually displayed in the browser) and change its formatting. Is it possible to do it using `DOMParser`?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Might get a bit complex if you have to check across multiple tags. If it's only raw text inside a sentence then it's fairly easy

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, that is what I need — to add formatting (e.g. underline or color) to the text across multiple tags. Are there some easy docs or recipees available?

Comment: Well as far as domparser goes if you are doing this in browser then any element you create uses built in domparser. If you don't find full match inside text of one node would need to look for partial matches at the end of it and look for the rest in next sibling. Then do replacements only within each text node and reset where the text node was with the new html

Comment: @charlietfl But how to apply appropriate tags after that inside all the existing tags?

Comment: That's where it gets a bit tricky and will take some time to build good tests. For example if next sibling doesn't start with a text node...look inside it's first child text

Comment: @charlietfl Then where to begin? I never used `domparser` (only once today to see that it works).

Comment: Here's a very basic concept of how to iterate through the various nodes http://jsfiddle.net/hz2194a7/. It doesn't begin to try matching anything...you will have to start that yourself

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks! But I cannot see, how to add `domparser` to your code. (sorry for a dumb question)

Comment: The dom in the browser window is the dom parser. Would only need an external one if you were working on this server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done using CSS (or alternatively XPath) selectors and some JavaScript. To make things even easier, throw jQuery into the mix, to get access to methods like [`.wrapInner`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

```js
$("p:nth-child(2)").wrapInner("<u></u>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<test>
<p>baz foobar</p><p>foo<i>bar</i></p>
</test>
```

and here is an example using a CSS query selector in vanilla JS:

```js
var wrapper = document.createElement("u");
var parent = document.querySelector("p:nth-child(2)");
var div = parent.appendChild(wrapper);
while(parent.firstChild !== wrapper)
    wrapper.appendChild(parent.firstChild);
```

```html
<p>baz foobar</p><p>foo<i>bar</i></p>
```

To get up to speed, here is a nice intro on that matter: [JavaScript HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)
and here is a very nice and playful introduction to CSS selectors: [CSS Diner](http://flukeout.github.io/).

---

Regarding your specific request, if you insist on using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) here is an attempt to

- find the start and end position of the substring in question and
- using a neat function to wrap the selected text with a tag of your choice.

To make things a little more interesting, I search for a substring that does not start a position 0 of the selected text from the HTML fragment. Simply change the regex pattern or pass 0 as start index to the `CustomWrapper` function, if you like.

```js
function CustomWrapper(ele, start, end, wrapper) {
  var len = ele.html().length;
  var selectedText = ele.html().substring(start, end);
  var replacement = '<'+wrapper+'>'+selectedText+'</'+wrapper+'>';
  ele.html(ele.html().substring(0, start) + replacement + ele.html().substring(end, len));
}

var secondEle = $("p:nth-child(2)");
 console.log(secondEle.html());
var re = /<i>ba/g;
match = re.exec(secondEle.html());
 console.log(match.index + '-' + re.lastIndex);
CustomWrapper(secondEle, match.index, re.lastIndex, 'u');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<test>
<p>baz foobar</p><p>foo<i>bar</i></p>
</test>
```

This sample contains a lot of nuts and bolts. Please ask if you need an explanation for something specific.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand, how it works, but I don't see anywhere in the solution the regex `/^fooba/g` and the result is different from what was expected (letter `r` should _not_ be underlined).

Comment: @EugeneBarsky My initial answer was general in outlook. I have addressed your question in my update.